# How to match width of divs css only

Tags: css, sass

Suppose I have this style:

[image]

What I would like is match the width of the bar with the video title.

This is my code:

```
<div className={styles.videoTitleContainer}>
   <div className={styles.videoTitle}>
            {videoProgress.status === VideoProgressStatusEnum.Finished
              ? (
                <img
                  src="/assets/icon-watched.svg"
                  alt="loading"
                  width={20}
                  height={20}
                  className={styles.videoStatusIcon}
                />
              )
              : (
                <img
                  src="/assets/icon-not-watched.svg"
                  alt="loading"
                  width={20}
                  height={20}
                  className={styles.videoStatusIcon}
                />
              )}<span style={{ position: 'absolute', paddingLeft: '0.5rem' }}>{video.title}</span>
            <ProgressBar progressInPercentage={1} />
         </div>
</div>
```

The progress bar component code:

```
<div>
    <div className={classes.progressBar}>
      <div
        style={{ width: `${100 * progressInPercentage}%` }}
        className={styles.progressBarContent}
      />
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.videoTitleContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  min-height: 22px;
}

.videoTitle {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin: 0 2rem 4rem 0rem;
  @media (min-width: 720px) {
    margin: 0 72px 0.4rem 0px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

.videoStatusIcon {
  margin: 0rem 0rem 0.4rem 2rem;
  @media (min-width: 720px) {
    margin: 0 0 0.4rem 72px;
  }
}

.progressBar {
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid colors.$secondary;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  @media (min-width: 720px) {
    width: 18%;
  }
}

.progressBarContent {
  height: 6px;
  background: colors.$primary;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

This is what I have working:

[image]
[image]

I was not able to match the width of the progress bar with the title of video.

Is there any way to achieve this with css only?
I am currently using Sass.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want the right edge of your text move with the progressing bar?

Comment: Yes, to match the proress bar with the text, n matter what text it is, like in the image above.

Comment: Put your text inside your progress bar, right aligned, when your bar grows the text will always be aligned with the right edge of the bar.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: I want the length of the bar to match the length of the video title, understand?

Comment: Do you want the 100% mark align with the right edge of the title? So they eventually align, but not in the beginning?